# How to move files from an Android Phone (Pixel) to a Windows PC?

Tags: windows, android, sync

I'm having a lot of problems with this, and not found any kind of resolution in the last 2 years.

I would simply like to get the contents of an entire folder on my Pixel 7 Pro and move them to my Windows PC. I find various sites like this mention it, but in a really awful and non-working way.

- https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2840804

Other sites just do variations of the above.

The problem is that my Pixel is full, 253 GB used of 256 GB. All of my personal photos and videos are archived in Google Photos, so I now want to move 80 GB of videos and photos from my Pixel phone to my Windows PC. I don't really mind how.

My experiences with the File Transfer setting in Android are awful: I enable this setting, then open Windows Explorer and navigate into the phone and then open another window in the empty folder on my PC that I want to move to. In Windows Explorer looking the Pixel folder, I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut the files, then go to the Windows folder and do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. It copies a lot of files, but it does not move the files, and the usage on the Pixel is unchanged. Then, it *always* crashes after a while, so I'm left with a completely broken situation.

Ideally, I'd like to mount the Pixel as an external drive (say X:) and just go into it and robocopy from there to the Windows PC (I get that it's some kind of Linux filesystem, but isn't there a way to just get the Pixel to completely synchronise a folder to my Windows PC?)

Comment: I like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resilio_Sync

Answer (score 0):

While Windows displays the contents of mobile device storage in ways that look like "normal" storage, this is an abstraction, something to make things simpler for most people.  You cannot "map" folders on mobile device to your computer or access these using normal file-movement command line tools.

**Things to check:**

- It is possible the cable you are using may have problems. Make sure the connections are firmly fitting at both ends, and that the cable is not obviously damaged or worn. Try a different cable if possible.

**Your available solutions are:**

- Use a third party tool, like Gantendo suggests in his comment. Resilio Sync a REALLY good tool actually, for ongoing sync or backup, but back when I used it, it works better for two way sync, and *may* require some configuring to get it to sync only one way for space-clearing backup like you want.
- Use PTP instead of MTP mode for the transfer. MTP allows you to navigate more of the phone's file system, but it could have issues in certain cases. Using PTP treats the phone like digital camera, and allows use of Windows' Photo Import tools, which are specifically designed for bulk transfer (import) of media (pictures and video).

However, you note you've already backed these files up to Google, which makes me wonder why you're trying to do this additional backup at all, or if you can just go to Google Drive on your computer and confirm the files are there already.